# Managing "active" and "rest" state for class name-based CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Started working with CSS animations and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to manage (with class names) when an animation is on or off. The general pattern I have is like this:

```
<div class="base-class"></div>
<div class="base-class base-class-rest"></div>
<div class="base-class base-class-active"></div>
```

I really dislike the idea of having a css class for `base-class-rest` that is different than just the `base-class`. I came up with this solution because I needed a css state that animates from the end of the `base-class-active` state back to a state of "rest". `base-class` alone cannot achieve this because there is no animation defined in its css.

**tl;dr:** I'm toggling a color on and off but I've written too much code for a task this simple. How can I write less code?

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpaJQa

**html**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**css**

```
@keyframes box-active {
    0% { background-color: black; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}

@keyframes box-rest {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: currentColor; }
}

.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.box-active {
    animation: box-active 1s 1 forwards;
}

.box-rest {
    animation: box-rest 1s 1 forwards;
}
```

**js**

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", click("box", "box-rest", "box-active"));
});

function click(none, rest, active) {
    return function(e) {
        var classname = e.target.className;
        var arr = classname.split(" ");
        var index = [arr.indexOf(none), arr.indexOf(rest), arr.indexOf(active)];
        //no state
        if (index[1] < 0 && index[2] < 0) {
            arr.push(active);
            return e.target.className = arr.join(" ");
        }
        //at rest
        if (index[2] > -1) {
            arr.splice(index[1], 1);
            arr.push(rest);
        }
        //active
        else {
            arr.splice(index[2], 1);
            arr.push(active);
        }
        e.target.className = arr.join(" ");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toggle` method from [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event in your example:

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box")).forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', click());
        el.addEventListener('animationend', resetBox());
    });

    function click() {
        return function(e) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if (target.classList.contains('box')) {
                if (target.classList.contains('box-active')) {
                    target.classList.toggle('box-rest');
                } else {
                    target.classList.toggle('box-active');
                }
            }
        };
    }

    function resetBox() {
        return function(e) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if (target.classList.contains('box-rest')) {
                target.className = 'box';
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```